# Is it possible to set up a lxc or docker container for a X application?

Tags: openssl, docker, chroot, lxc, qt

I need to use the Cisco packet tracer for college(I use Debian testing). Now I actually like that application, except it has one annoyance... it needs an ancient libssl version to run. What is even funnier is that their installer does not list it as a dependency, but it just refuses to launch.

Now when I install the old library alongisde the new libraries, some(rare) other applications, mostly some QT based applications will get confused and then they don't launch:

```
./otter-browser: relocation error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: symbol EVP_seed_cbc, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
```

So now my questions are: Is there a simple way to install a container or chroot(hopefully debian based), install packet tracer in it, install that ancient openssl library on it? How?
Can containers run X applications in the same X session that my only monitor uses?
Can I copy paste between my host and the container?

Comment: systemd-nspawn generally works ok.  It avoids dealing with Docker's opinions.  Punching holes for X apparently isn't too hard.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-nspawn#Use_an_X_environment

Comment: have you tried putting a copy of the old libssl into a directory and then using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/old/ssl/dir:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ./otter-browser`?  that can be put in a wrapper script, of course.

Comment: It's otter that needs the new library and packettracer that needs the old one. But your suggestion seems like something worth experimenting.

Comment: @cas I have investigated the startup script of packettracer and I have seen that this script uses it's own LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable and puts it into /opt/pt/lib. So i did sudo mv /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl1.0.0.so /opt/pt/lib and now both programs work. Put this into an answer so I can upvote it and mark as correct.

Comment: if you get it working, please write it up as an answer here.  It's OK to accept your own answer.